# Change word colour from sentence with regex

Tags: swift, string, uicolor

I have sentence "This is my first test", I need to change for example word "first" to another colour. But this sentences will come from backend. So,i need maybe with regex take word from sentence, and back it with another colour.
How to back this word into sentence, or maybe better way to change colour of word from sentence?

```
     var string = "This is my text=\"first\" test!"
        let pattern = ".*(?=( - text=\"[\\w\\s]+\"))|(?<=text=\")([\\w\\s]+)"

        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
            let matches = regex.matches(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count))
            for match in matches {
                if let range = Range(match.range, in: string) {
                    let name = string[range]
                    if let range = string.range(of: "text=\"\(name)\"") {
                        string.removeSubrange(range)
                        debugPrint("WORD CHANGE COLOR: \(name)") // first
                        debugPrint("PHRASE IS: \(string)") // This is my test!
                    }
                    let attrs1 = [NSAttributedString.Key.font :  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.green]
                    let attrs2 = [NSAttributedString.Key.font :  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black]
                    let attributedString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: String(name),attributes:attrs1)
                    let attributedString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.phrase, attributes: attrs2)
                    
                    titleLabel.attributedText = attributedString1
//                    titleLabel.attributedText = attributedString2
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Regex was bad!")
        }
```

Comment: What is not working for you ? As an example, I did something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70929250/1619193 which was adding color to when an ellipsis was encountered, you just need to replace it with your word

Comment: @ShawnFrank I can't remove from all sentence this word and back it again with another colour.

Comment: Do I understand your request correctly. You will get a sentence from the server `This is my first test`, and you will get a string also from the server like `first` so the  text `first` inside `This is my first test` should have a color in it's background ?

Comment: Clarify the logic on how to find the word to color (in words, an explanation, not necessary by code), and explain exactly what's wrong with your code, it's unclear.

Comment: @ShawnFrank Yes) I need take word for example "first", from sentence, and change colour. now I updated code in example, I can separate word what I need, and sentence. but how to insert back this word to sentence?

Comment: @Larme we will find this word with regex,  for example like in code. My problem is that I can't insert this word back to sentence. because now it's attributedString, and how to back to first position (I mean where it was) this word?

Comment: " how to back to first position" ?

Comment: The word `first` is already in your string. Regex gives you `position` of this word in your string. It does not **remove** it from your string so you don't have to put anything back. You just have to tell attributedString what range should be updated with attributes like background color.

Comment: @ShawnFrank, but how to update it?

Comment: @Larme I mean, where it was

Comment: I didn't see the `self.phrase`, which I guess is from where is extract the `string`?. What's your regex pattern? What's `phrase` value (as sample)? And I guess that previously `titleLabel.text = phrase`?

Comment: @Larme, sorry updated code

Comment: @helloPubick - is something like this what you are trying to do: http://prntscr.com/fUAy4WpqvE7Y or something else ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank yes!) u changed colour in regex word) I need the same) but without regex, I mean : text=\" \"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution (with extra initial values to be usable in Playgrounds).

What's the idea:
Work directly on a `NS(Mutable)AttributedString`.
Change the regex pattern, to let you know what's the real full range, what's the range of "first".
Enumerate the matches in reverse (because you'll be modifying the string, so the ranges won't be valid afterwards, since replacement won't have the same length)

```
let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
titleLabel.backgroundColor = .blue


let string = "This is my text=\"first\" test!"
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font :  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black])

let pattern = "text=\"([\\w\\s]+)\""

do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
    let matches = regex.matches(in: attributedString.string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))

    for match in matches.reversed() {
        let globalNSRange = match.range
        let worldNSRange = match.range(at: 1)
        let replacement = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString.attributedSubstring(from: worldNSRange))
        replacement.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font :  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20),
                                   NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.green],
                                  range: NSRange(location: 0, length: replacement.length))
        attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: globalNSRange, with: replacement)
    }

    titleLabel.attributedText = attributedString
} catch {
    print("Regex was bad: \(error)") //Print useful information on why it failed, like the actual thrown error
}

return titleLabel
```